# Initialize ng-include scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I need to initialize the `ng-include` inner scope with some data. Until now, I was using `ng-init` at the `ng-include` element itself, but this way the evaluated expression is saved on the `ng-include` parent scope, and conflicts can appear if two directives use the same names.

There are some ways to resolve this, until now I've tried this:

Use a dummy ng-if to force the creation of a new scope:

```
 <div ng-if="true">
      <ng-include src="'/partials/reports/chart'" ng-init="chart=getChartParams()"></ng-include>
 </div>
```

Use a children element to initialize the `ng-include` scope:

```
 <ng-include src="'/partials/reports/chart'">
                        <span ng-init="chart=getChartParams()"></span>
 </ng-include>
```

This solutions are functional, but they're ugly hacks. Is there any better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ngInclude` has an **`onload`** attribute that does what you want. It works like `ng-init`, but acts on the newly-created scope.

```
 <ng-include src="'/partials/reports/chart'" onload="chart=getChartParams()">
 </ng-include>
```

The [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude) says `onload` is an "expression to evaluate when a new partial is loaded" but offers no guidance as to usage. I don't know whether this is the intended use of this attribute, but it does the trick.

Comment: This answer was accepted with zero votes. There should be a badge for that. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You should also be able to use an arbitrary attribute with double curly braces to evaluate an expression on the scope.

```
<ng-include src="'/partials/reports/chart'" whatever="{{chart=getChartParams()}}"></ng-include>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this creating a custom directive, based on the original `ngInit`, but with a lower priority than `ngInclude`:

```
app.directive('init', function () {
    return {
        priority: 0,
        compile: function () {
            return {
                pre: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                    scope.$eval(attrs.init);
                }
            };
        }
    };
});
```

You can use it like this:

```
<ng-include src="'/partials/reports/chart'" init="chart=getChartParams()"></ng-include>
```

The init expression will be executed just after the ngInclude scope is created, before loading or executing anything of the inner template.